# Webconfig URL Rewrite to Hide Classic ASP ext but not .aspx or other ext

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, asp-classic, web-config

I have been able to hide the .asp extension, but it also removes any other extensions and points to .asp
I know this is just a config issue but have no experience of the webconfig file configuration and wonder if anyone has a quick solution to save me a few hrs!
Code as I have it below from  part of webconfig file

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Hide .asp Ext">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.asp" matchType="IsFile" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.asp" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
      </rule>
      <rule name="Redirect .asp Ext" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="^(.*).asp" ignoreCase="true" />
           <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*).asp" />
           </conditions>
           <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
       </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this? Seems to work on my test server.

```xml
        <rule name ="redirect .asp to none" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)\.asp$" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>                  
        <rule name="hide .asp extension" stopProcessing="false">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.asp" />
        </rule>
```

Comment: Yep that did it. Changed the Rewrite backreference to {R:0}.asp as it made more sense, but seems to work either way I think. Thanks very much for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me the first rule converts everything to an .asp extension first?

Try removing the first rule.

Answer (score 0):

You have two rules defined.  It looks like the first matches on all requests and "rewrites" them to have a .asp extension.  The second matches on on .asp and then performs a redirect of some kind.

What is not clear from your question is how you want to 'hide' these files.  If you want to deny all requests to .asp you would be much better served adding a Request Filtering "File Extensions" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/fileextensions/index

Comment: Hi Rich-Lang, I want (and is working) to hide the .asp extension, but when I try and visit .net (aspx etc) files the rule hides these as well and gives a 404 error.

Comment: @DavidBarclay its not clear what 'hide' means.  I'll say again that RequestFiltering is probably how you should do this.  Upon further inspection, your 2nd rule, try adding $ to the end of the match URL.    $ in regex means "end of string".  Let me know if .asp is still blocked though.

Comment: by "hide" I mean remove, get ride of. I want to convert all urls to remove the ".asp" extension, however I dont want to remove extensions of other pages, only ".asp" pages.